# Pushing a commit from one repository into another repository

Tags: git

Is it possible for me to push a commit from one Git repository into a branch of *another* Git repository?

So for example, I have a commit `aaaa` in Repository A. Commit `aaaa` is in a branch called "Testing". I want to push commit `aaaa` into a branch called "Stable" which is in another repository called Repository B. When pushed into Repository B from A, the new commit to Repository B should be an exact image of commit `aaaa`, ie, replacing all of the files in the branch "Stable" in Repository B with the ones from A.

If this is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
git push repositoryb aaaa:Stable
```

I am assuming `repositoryb` is a remote pointing to the other repo. And if you haven't come to grips with git, the above pushes the commits upto `aaaa` and not just `aaaa`.

Comment: The situation I have now is that RepositoryB is a Git address. I'm using BitBucket, and every repository has its own address given by them. So, before running this command, should I be in RepositoryA and checked out in the branch "Testing"?

Comment: The above solution doesn't care about your Testing branch. But of course, you have to be in the repositoryA.

Comment: Since this command will push all earlier commits in RepositoryA too which may be too much to push in my case, is it possible to set a range of commits to push from RepositoryA? Say like aaaa1 to aaaa3 into RepositoryB of branch Stable? Also, I would replace the RepositoryB with its Git address, right?

Comment: I get an error saying that this is a non-fast-forward error. It says that "Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote". But all I really want, is to push and overwrite everything from commit `aaaa` into RepositoryB's `Stable` branch.

Comment: Do `git push -f repositoryb aaaa:Stable`