# Transfer commits from one account to another?

Tags: git

I have control over two accounts: the workstation account at my place of work, and a personal/professional account. I'd really like to transfer commits from the former to the latter in Git.

I have the username/password combination for **both** accounts.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post. You don't have to remove your current repo though.
[How to migrate GIT repository from one server to a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one)

EDIT: Try manojlds soultion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616133/pushing-a-commit-from-one-repository-into-another-repository) . let me know if this works

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related

Comment: @TimCastelijns I may have misread.  Luke do you only want to transfer the recent changes?

Comment: I'm hoping to move individual commits. I'd be satisfied with moving all f the commits in bulk if that's all I can do, but obviously the more flexibility the better.